# Access android system files when running through emulator

Tags: java, android

I have just written some code which creates a file "config.txt" and writes some data to it, but the problem is I do not know where to find this file to check whether the data is correct or not.

Could someone please tell me which directory to look under.

I am using the android emulator to test my apps.

Thanks,

Callum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you created the file: it could be in a number of places.  If you didn't put it on the SD Card, however, the most likely place to find it is:

/data/data/

So, if your Manifest declares your application like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.app"
```

Then your file will be somewhere in the directory

/data/data/com.my.app/

Comment: Ah ok thankyou, so if I followed the path apk/res/android/data/data/com.my.app I should find it there?

Comment: Not quite.  If it is running code, on the phone, that is creating the file, it will be in: /data/data/com.my.app/...

Comment: Ah ok, so under that directory in the phone emulator; is where I will find my file....thankyou! +1

Comment: How will you try to find the file? With code in your app? With FileExplorer in Eclipse? With a file explorer app on the emulator?

Comment: @user3744373 Yeah, exactly.  Probably "adb shell", then "cd /data/data/<your package name>"